# Unable to convert json file in dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, machine-learning

I am building an recommendation engine. This json file contains event data, I want to convert it into a dataframe. I tried read_json method but it give an error

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError:'charmap'codec can't decode byte 0x81 
> in position 21573281:charactermaps to <undefined>
> ```

Below is some entries from json:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d194f"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160803-001810481"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"OfferViewed","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183505399"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{"Category":"120000","CustomerID":"4078","OfferID":"45436"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1950"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160803-001810481"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"ContextMenuItemSelected","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183500206"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{"MenuItem":"OfferList","CustomerID":"4078"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1951"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160803-001810481"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"CategoryPageCategorySelection","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183499171"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{"Category":"Recharge","CustomerID":"4078"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1952"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160803-001810481"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"_session.start","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{"CustomerID":"4078"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1953"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470181311752"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160802-234151752","stop_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470181484875"}},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"_session.stop","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490480"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1954"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193238841"},"session_id":"7b606a93-20160803-030038841"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193295093"},"event_type":"_session.start","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193238844"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"2","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"1.0.2","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:e96515c9-5824-4c66-a42f-33cceb78b6e3","client_id":"efed74fd-40d8-41a2-b37e-e85c7b606a93"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"GB","code":"en_GB","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"samsung","model":"SM-J200G"},"attributes":{}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1955"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193253960"},"session_id":"7b606a93-20160803-030053960","stop_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193256359"}},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193404776"},"event_type":"_session.stop","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193278227"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"2","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"1.0.2","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:e96515c9-5824-4c66-a42f-33cceb78b6e3","client_id":"efed74fd-40d8-41a2-b37e-e85c7b606a93"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"GB","code":"en_GB","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"samsung","model":"SM-J200G"},"attributes":{}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1956"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193253960"},"session_id":"7b606a93-20160803-030053960"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193404776"},"event_type":"_session.start","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193253960"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"2","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"1.0.2","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:e96515c9-5824-4c66-a42f-33cceb78b6e3","client_id":"efed74fd-40d8-41a2-b37e-e85c7b606a93"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"GB","code":"en_GB","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"samsung","model":"SM-J200G"},"attributes":{}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1957"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193238841"},"session_id":"7b606a93-20160803-030038841","stop_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193244581"}},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193404776"},"event_type":"_session.stop","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193253959"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"2","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"1.0.2","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:e96515c9-5824-4c66-a42f-33cceb78b6e3","client_id":"efed74fd-40d8-41a2-b37e-e85c7b606a93"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"GB","code":"en_GB","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"samsung","model":"SM-J200G"},"attributes":{}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d1958"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193331290"},"session_id":"7b606a93-20160803-030211290"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193404776"},"event_type":"_session.start","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470193331291"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"2","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"1.0.2","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:e96515c9-5824-4c66-a42f-33cceb78b6e3","client_id":"efed74fd-40d8-41a2-b37e-e85c7b606a93"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"GB","code":"en_GB","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"samsung","model":"SM-J200G"},"attributes":{}}
```

Comment: Please fervid more code helping explain what you have used already

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82782503/Analytics%20Assignment.zip

Comment: above is the link to that json file the name of file is event_data.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong encoding. Explicitely read it as `utf-8` e.g. (edit: +'dirty' Line Feeds (LF aka. `\n`)

```
with open(datafilename, encoding="utf8") as f:
   # Reading file as list of lines
   data = f.readlines()

   # Removing useless whitespaces
   data = [line.rstrip() for line in data]

   # Joining lines together
   data = ''.join(data)

# Loading dataframe from json str
df = pandas.read_json(datafile)
```

Comment: I just ran it on your file, and its ok on my side. Did you run it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
import json

with open('myfile.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
```

Without more info its difficult to advise.

Comment: thnx for trying but it did not work still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have an issue with the encoding. When you read in the file, you need to change the encoding:

```
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```